# Burned DVD essentially has no content and the DVD is not bootable when creating on Mac OSX

Tags: iso, macosx, burning

I have been unsuccessful when burning downloaded ISOs to a DVD on OSX - the burned DVD essentially has no content and the DVD is not bootable. I've tried Ubuntu versions of 11.x and 12.04 with no success. Further, I took the DVD out of an Ubuntu Unleashed book (v11.x), and am unable on several OSX laptops to read the DVD.

The applications to manage ISO disks on OSX are really straightforward, and they properly function with ISOs of other linux distributions. Is there a problem with Ubuntu's? Or is it just me?

Comment: The OSX ISO manager is incompatible with the standard(?) format of ISOs Ubuntu uses(which most other programs support).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure SimplyBurns does ISO's. It's a decent alternative to the built in ISO Burner if that isn't working for you. It can be found at http://simplyburns.sourceforge.net/